# Change Sharepoint group setting using JSOM or REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, groups

I am looking for JSOM or REST option to update SharePoint user group settings who can edit the membership for the group.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly which settings do you want to update?

Microsoft provided detailed documentation on Users, groups, and roles using REST API in below article:

[Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)).

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeGroup(){
    var groupName="LZ Members";
    var allowMembersEditMembership=true;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+groupName+"')",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Group' }, 'AllowMembersEditMembership': allowMembersEditMembership }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="ChangeGroup" onclick="changeGroup()"/>
```